# Can't run Eclipse after installing ADT Plugin

Tags: windows, configuration, android, eclipse, paths

So, I've installed the ADT Plugin, run a HelloWorld, restart my computer and after that the Eclipse can't run. A message appear:

"An error has ocurred. See the log file: /home/todi (...)"

Here is the log file:

> !SESSION 2011-07-26 22:51:59.381
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736 java.version=1.6.0_26 java.vendor=Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32,
>   NL=pt_BR Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product Command-line arguments:  -os
>   win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2011-07-26 22:57:34.135
>   !MESSAGE Could not rename configuration temp file
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2011-07-26 22:57:34.157
>   !MESSAGE Unable to save configuration file "C:\Program
>   Files\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.update\platform.xml.tmp"
>   !STACK 0 java.io.IOException: Unable to save configuration file
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.update\platform.xml.tmp"  at
>   org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.PlatformConfiguration.save(PlatformConfiguration.java:690)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.PlatformConfiguration.save(PlatformConfiguration.java:574)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.PlatformConfiguration.startup(PlatformConfiguration.java:714)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.ConfigurationActivator.getPlatformConfiguration(ConfigurationActivator.java:404)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.ConfigurationActivator.initialize(ConfigurationActivator.java:136)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.ConfigurationActivator.start(ConfigurationActivator.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.createInstance(ServiceComponent.java:480)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.createInstance(ServiceComponentProp.java:271)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.ServiceReg.getService(ServiceReg.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse$1.run(ServiceUse.java:138)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse.getService(ServiceUse.java:136)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:468)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:594)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.addingService(ServiceTracker.java:450)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:980)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:262)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:185)
>     at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:348)
>     at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:283)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getBundleGroupProviders(InternalPlatform.java:225)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundleGroupProviders(Platform.java:1261)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin.getFeatureInfos(IDEWorkbenchPlugin.java:291)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder.makeFeatureDependentActions(WorkbenchActionBuilder.java:1217)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder.makeActions(WorkbenchActionBuilder.java:1026)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.ActionBarAdvisor.fillActionBars(ActionBarAdvisor.java:147)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder.fillActionBars(WorkbenchActionBuilder.java:341)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.fillActionBars(WorkbenchWindow.java:3564)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.(WorkbenchWindow.java:419)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.tweaklets.Workbench3xImplementation.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench3xImplementation.java:31)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.newWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1920)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$14(Workbench.java:1918)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$68.runWithException(Workbench.java:3658)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2011-07-27 00:15:28.049
>   !MESSAGE Operation details !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
>   4 1 2011-07-27 00:15:28.049 !MESSAGE Cannot complete the install
>   because some dependencies are not satisfiable !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2011-07-27 00:15:28.049 !MESSAGE
>   org.eclipse.linuxtools.callgraph.feature.group [0.0.2.201106060936]
>   cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not
>   applicable.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2011-07-27 00:15:28.644
>   !MESSAGE Operation details !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
>   4 1 2011-07-27 00:15:28.644 !MESSAGE Cannot complete the install
>   because some dependencies are not satisfiable !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2011-07-27 00:15:28.644 !MESSAGE
>   org.eclipse.linuxtools.callgraph.feature.group [0.0.2.201106060936]
>   cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not
>   applicable.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2011-07-27 00:27:35.152
>   !MESSAGE Operation details !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
>   4 1 2011-07-27 00:27:35.158 !MESSAGE Cannot complete the install
>   because some dependencies are not satisfiable !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2011-07-27 00:27:35.159 !MESSAGE
>   org.eclipse.linuxtools.callgraph.feature.group [0.0.2.201106060936]
>   cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not
>   applicable.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2011-07-27 00:27:35.215
>   !MESSAGE Operation details !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
>   4 1 2011-07-27 00:27:35.216 !MESSAGE Cannot complete the install
>   because some dependencies are not satisfiable !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2011-07-27 00:27:35.216 !MESSAGE
>   org.eclipse.linuxtools.callgraph.feature.group [0.0.2.201106060936]
>   cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not
>   applicable.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2011-07-27 01:07:17.988
>   !MESSAGE Operation details !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
>   4 1 2011-07-27 01:07:18.006 !MESSAGE Cannot complete the install
>   because some dependencies are not satisfiable !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2011-07-27 01:07:18.006 !MESSAGE
>   org.eclipse.linuxtools.callgraph.feature.group [0.0.2.201106060936]
>   cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not
>   applicable.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2011-07-27 01:07:19.847
>   !MESSAGE Operation details !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
>   4 1 2011-07-27 01:07:19.848 !MESSAGE Cannot complete the install
>   because some dependencies are not satisfiable !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2011-07-27 01:07:19.848 !MESSAGE
>   org.eclipse.linuxtools.callgraph.feature.group [0.0.2.201106060936]
>   cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not
>   applicable.

I don't understand how the path windows like has appeared... if anyone knows how to solve this, I'll appreciate!

Thank you for all your answers!

Best regards,
Alexandre Ferreira.

Comment: Do you have any intersection point between your Linux `eclipse` configuration and your Windows' one? Is there any chance that you have rebooted into Windows, launched `eclipse` and then rebooted again into Linux?

Comment: No... but, before I started to use Eclipse in Ubuntu, I've coded some programs in the Eclipse using Windows. Then, I copied the folder with codes I've been done in Windows to a folder in Ubuntu. Is this a problem?

Comment: It seems it is. Try to separate what has been used in Windows from what is used only in Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, it is. Now, everything works fine! Thanks guys! :-)

Comment: You're welcome! If you want, you can answer to your own question and then mark your answer as accepted. So people with problems similar to yours that find this thread will know that yours is a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's just move the folders with java codes on windows to another folder and then start eclipse again. Everything works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) to help you in your problem

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you provide detail on the link here please. Thanks!